Django Email Sending
I have a django project but when i try to use send_email() i get the following error:
PS> daphne -p 8000 Server.asgi:application
2024-06-26 11:36:00,313 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2024-06-26 11:36:00,313 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2024-06-26 11:36:00,313 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2024-06-26 11:36:00,314 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000








xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx








Internal Server Error: /Http/createUser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 534, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 534, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 479, in __call__
    ret: _R = await loop.run_in_executor(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] The connected person does not respond within a certain period of time or the established
connection could not be established because the connecting host was not responding
2024-06-26 11:37:01,353 ERROR    Internal Server Error: /Http/createUser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 534, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 534, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 479, in __call__
    ret: _R = await loop.run_in_executor(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] The connected person does not respond within a certain period of time or the established
connection could not be established because the connecting host was not responding
127.0.0.1:60554 - - [26/Jun/2024:11:37:01] "POST /Http/createUser" 500 50886

Here r the files that im using:
Settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
    'channels',
    'rest_framework',

    'Http',
    'WebSocket',
]
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myEmail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myPassword'
#DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myEmail' # no-reply

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]


# Is Gonna Change Manually 
FRONTEND_URL = '127.0.0.1:8000'

urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "Http"
urlpatterns = [
    path('createUser', views.create_user, name='CreateUser'),
    path('verifyEmail/', views.verify_email, name='VerifyEmail'),
]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt # No Csrf Prot
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.http import JsonResponse
from . import models as DataBase


from rest_framework import status # type: ignore
from rest_framework.response import Response # type: ignore
from rest_framework.views import APIView # type: ignore
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .token_generator import emailVerificationToken

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():

        user = serializer.save()

        return Response({
            'message': 'User created successfully. Check your email for verification.',
            'user_id': user.id
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET'])
def verify_email(request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    user = get_object_or_404(DataBase.User, email=email)

    if emailVerificationToken.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Email verified successfully.'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid token or email.'}, status=400)

serializers.py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers # type: ignore
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import ExtraClasses_EmailVerification
from .token_generator import emailVerificationToken

User = get_user_model()

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'phoneNumber')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        
        token = emailVerificationToken.make_token(user)
        verification_record = ExtraClasses_EmailVerification.objects.create(user=user, token=token)

        verification_url = f"{settings.FRONTEND_URL}/Http/verifyEmail?token={token}&email={user.email}"

        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        send_mail(
            'Verify your email',
            f'Click the link to verify your email: {verification_url}',
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [user.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        return user


models.py
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField # type: ignore
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class ExtraClasses_CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(name=name, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(name, email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Users That Use The Program
    """
    profilePhoto = models.ImageField(upload_to='profileImages/', default='defaultImages/profileImage.png')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    explanation = models.CharField(max_length=48)

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    """
    Django Authentication Parts
    """

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = ExtraClasses_CustomUserManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class ExtraClasses_EmailVerification(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

I checked if the problem is internet connection but its not (i added '-------'s )
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName smtp.gmail.com -Port 587                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ComputerName     : smtp.gmail.com                                                                                                                RemoteAddress    : --------------                                                                                                               RemotePort       : 587                                                                                                                           InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi                                                                                                                         SourceAddress    : --------------                                                                                                                  TcpTestSucceeded : True  

I checked if its due to router and nslookup smtp.gmail.com on cmd is working in other computers but not in mine so ik its not due to router,
I checked if its due to firewall but its not cause i still get the same errors even when i try it with all firewalls of

A similar question was asked here:
Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time
Testing if the HTTP port is closed (or 'not accessible') on your machine was recommended. If not, the port's access to www.python.org could be blocked possibly because of a firewall.
